# Form fields generated by Spring Roo

Tags: spring, dojo, spring-roo, jsp-tags

Does anyone know how to customize the form fields that Spring Roo generates so I can change the with of the associated label?

For example,

```
<field:input field="firstName" id="c_com_myclass_Person_firstname" label="What is your first name?" z=""/>
```

The field is rendered inside a div that is the full width of the screen, but the label is split onto two lines as if the tag has decided to give the label e.g. 50px width or something. e.g.

```
What is  
your first name?:
```

There's no 'style' attribute on the tag and I can't find anything that looks like it would let me control the width.

Thanks

Comment: Ignore me. I found the answer 5 seconds after posting this. It's in the standard.css duh - class label has a 100px fixed width. Was so obsessed with finding in extracted dijit tundra css files I forgot to check the obvious...

Comment: In your case I would post your solution as answer and mark it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the standard.css - class label has a 100px fixed width. Was so obsessed with finding in extracted dijit tundra css files I forgot to check the obvious.

Have to say, there are lots of things I like about Roo, but the tag libs and dijit stuff make working with the presentation side of things a real chore if you want to customise the appearence of your app...